# How do I find a string pattern in Notepad++, remove a space, and insert a comma?

Tags: notepad++, regex

So, after a week of working with Regex, looking at 100s of google search results, and getting incredible help on here, I’ve become moderately comfortable at finding strings using “Find what”.  But the logic of “Replace with” still makes my head explode.

I have 1000s of lines in Notepad++ that has “1st Dam” abutting against a capitalized letter, like this:

```
1st DamTEACHMEHOWTO
1st DamTEAGARDEN
```

I need to change “1st Dam” into “1stDam, “ so that a comma and space precede the former capitalized word, like this:

```
1stDam, TEACHMEHOWTO
1stDam, TEAGARDEN
```

I can find the pattern I want changed in “Find what” with

```
1st Dam[A-Z]
```

But I can’t figure out what to put in  “Replace with”.  This code approximates what I'm looking for:

```
1st Dam,
```

But of course it deletes the first capitalized letter.

I’d appreciate any help.  Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

- Find what: `(Dam)(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\1,`  (there is a space after the comma)
- Search mode: Regular expression

**Explanation:**

- `(Dam)`: matches Dam
- (?=[A-Z]): positive look-ahead to match a single character

If Dam is followed by a capital letter, replaces it with Dam followed by a comma and a space.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you, Reddy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [capturing groups](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html?wlr=1) for parts you want to keep :

- find what `1st Dam([A-Z])`
- replace to: `1stDam, $1`

Comment: Works!  Thank you, Máté Juhász!

Answer (score 0):

A solution without capture groups:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `1st Dam\K(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `,`   <-- there is a space after the comma
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
1st Dam         # literally
\K              # Reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
(?=[A-Z])       # positive lookahead, make sure we have a capital after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]